# iOS how to navigate from AppDelegate to the rootview after re-entering app

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I'm still relatively new to iOS programming.

With my first app, i want to be able to handle when user leaves and re-entering the app. I want the user to always go back to the rootview, which is a navigation view. (i also want any modal view to be dismissed as well)

This is what i've done currently. It works but I'm pretty sure it's not right:

```
    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
       self.window!.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)      
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        var vc = self.window!.rootViewController!
        vc.loadView()
    }
```

Could you please let me know how should i do it?

Additionally, I tried to get the navigation controller but

```
self.window!.rootviewController!.navigationController
```

is always nil for some reason

Answer (score 0):

```
presentViewController( UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourNavigationControllerID") as! UINavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!! should i put this in applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)  or func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)?

also does this automatically dismiss my previous views?

Comment: why don't you just dismisst the last one at applicationWillResignActive